# Unable to start rails server for a rails application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I was trying to learn rails and installed ruby on rails on my system. Though I already had an old version of ruby & rails installed. I installed this one as guided in the tutorials and installed a new version of ruby & rails.

I was able to install everything but not able to run `rails server`. As it is showing me a lot of errors.

```
Could not find gem 'pg (>= 0.18, < 2.0)' in any of the gem sources listed in your Gemfile. Run `bundle install` to install missing gems.
```

Once I run `bundle install`, it showing me more errors and not able to install certain bundles.

Showing the list of errors:

```
Gem::Ext::BuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    current directory: /home/<user>/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.3/gems/pg-1.1.3/ext
/usr/share/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.3/bin/ruby -r ./siteconf20181122-27002-nh4k6r.rb extconf.rb
checking for pg_config... yes
Using config values from /usr/bin/pg_config
checking for libpq-fe.h... yes
checking for libpq/libpq-fs.h... yes
checking for pg_config_manual.h... yes
checking for PQconnectdb() in -lpq... no
checking for PQconnectdb() in -llibpq... no
checking for PQconnectdb() in -lms/libpq... no
Can't find the PostgreSQL client library (libpq)
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
    --with-opt-dir
    --without-opt-dir
    --with-opt-include
    --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
    --with-opt-lib
    --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
    --with-make-prog
    --without-make-prog
    --srcdir=.
    --curdir
    --ruby=/usr/share/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.3/bin/$(RUBY_BASE_NAME)
    --with-pg
    --without-pg
    --enable-windows-cross
    --disable-windows-cross
    --with-pg-config
    --without-pg-config
    --with-pg_config
    --without-pg_config
    --with-pg-dir
    --without-pg-dir
    --with-pg-include
    --without-pg-include=${pg-dir}/include
    --with-pg-lib
    --without-pg-lib=${pg-dir}/lib
    --with-pqlib
    --without-pqlib
    --with-libpqlib
    --without-libpqlib
    --with-ms/libpqlib
    --without-ms/libpqlib

To see why this extension failed to compile, please check the mkmf.log which can be found here:

  /home/<user>/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.3/extensions/x86_64-linux/2.5.0/pg-1.1.3/mkmf.log

extconf failed, exit code 1

Gem files will remain installed in /home/<user>/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.3/gems/pg-1.1.3 for inspection.
Results logged to /home/<user>/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.3/extensions/x86_64-linux/2.5.0/pg-1.1.3/gem_make.out

An error occurred while installing pg (1.1.3), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install pg -v '1.1.3' --source 'https://rubygems.org/'` succeeds before bundling.

In Gemfile:
  pg
```

I know there are many posts related to this issue. I tried many and still not able to figure out, how to fix it. And I don't want to reinstall Ubuntu for this issue.

```
Can't find the PostgreSQL client library (libpq)
```

About this line. I have tried to install this package for like 10 times but it's not working.

I also tried to clean up all the packages using `rvm cleanup all` but that is not working as well. I am having a lot of permissions errors, showing a sample error below:

```
chmod: changing permissions of ‘/usr/share/rvm/src/rvm/binscripts’: Operation not permitted
chmod: changing permissions of ‘/usr/share/rvm/src/rvm/docs’: Operation not permitted
chmod: changing permissions of ‘/usr/share/rvm/src/rvm/hooks’: Operation not permitted
chmod: changing permissions of ‘/usr/share/rvm/src/rvm/rvm-test-rvm1’: Operation not permitted
chmod: changing permissions of ‘/usr/share/rvm/src/rvm/config’: Operation not permitted
chmod: changing permissions of ‘/usr/share/rvm/src/rvm/config/solaris’: Operation not permitted
chmod: changing permissions of ‘/usr/share/rvm/src/rvm/contrib’: Operation not permitted
chmod: changing permissions of ‘/usr/share/rvm/src/rvm/contrib/hudson’: Operation not permitted
chmod: changing permissions of ‘/usr/share/rvm/src/rvm/rvm-test’: Operation not permitted
 - failed removing /usr/share/rvm/src/rvm - please check ownership and permissions
```

I have 2 ruby version installed ruby "2.1.5" and "2.5.3". I have installed the new ruby application using "2.5.3". However, the older one required "2.1.5". I want to use ruby application using Postgres. I had Postgres 9.6 on my system earlier but now new installation installed Postgres 11. I am using Ubuntu 14.04. Can anyone help?

### Thanks

@Mark:
On `sudo apt-get update`. I am getting the following errors:

```
Reading package lists... Done
W: An error occurred during the signature verification. The repository is not updated and the previous index files will be used. GPG error: http://extras.ubuntu.com trusty Release: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 16126D3A3E5C1192

W: Failed to fetch http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty/Release  

W: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

I am going to following the next step now.

I was able to install the postgres and now creating new rails App. This step is showing me error. The full output is too large to add here, so I am going to share the error part here:

```
Fetching pg 1.1.3
Installing pg 1.1.3 with native extensions
Gem::Ext::BuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    current directory: /home/<user>/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.3/gems/pg-1.1.3/ext
/usr/share/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.3/bin/ruby -r ./siteconf20181122-4385-1kobagm.rb extconf.rb
checking for pg_config... yes
Using config values from /usr/bin/pg_config
checking for libpq-fe.h... yes
checking for libpq/libpq-fs.h... yes
checking for pg_config_manual.h... yes
checking for PQconnectdb() in -lpq... no
checking for PQconnectdb() in -llibpq... no
checking for PQconnectdb() in -lms/libpq... no
Can't find the PostgreSQL client library (libpq)
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
    --with-opt-dir
    --without-opt-dir
    --with-opt-include
    --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
    --with-opt-lib
    --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
    --with-make-prog
    --without-make-prog
    --srcdir=.
    --curdir
    --ruby=/usr/share/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.3/bin/$(RUBY_BASE_NAME)
    --with-pg
    --without-pg
    --enable-windows-cross
    --disable-windows-cross
    --with-pg-config
    --without-pg-config
    --with-pg_config
    --without-pg_config
    --with-pg-dir
    --without-pg-dir
    --with-pg-include
    --without-pg-include=${pg-dir}/include
    --with-pg-lib
    --without-pg-lib=${pg-dir}/lib
    --with-pqlib
    --without-pqlib
    --with-libpqlib
    --without-libpqlib
    --with-ms/libpqlib
    --without-ms/libpqlib

To see why this extension failed to compile, please check the mkmf.log which can be found here:

  /home/<user>/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.3/extensions/x86_64-linux/2.5.0/pg-1.1.3/mkmf.log

extconf failed, exit code 1

Gem files will remain installed in /home/<user>/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.3/gems/pg-1.1.3 for inspection.
Results logged to /home/<user>/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.3/extensions/x86_64-linux/2.5.0/pg-1.1.3/gem_make.out

An error occurred while installing pg (1.1.3), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install pg -v '1.1.3' --source 'https://rubygems.org/'` succeeds before bundling.

In Gemfile:
  pg
         run  bundle exec spring binstub --all
bundler: command not found: spring
Install missing gem executables with `bundle install`
```

here comes that `pg` error again. :(

Comment: What `psql` command print in terminal ?

Comment: `Warning: No existing local cluster is suitable as a default target. Please see man pg_wrapper(1) how to specify one.
Error: You must install at least one postgresql-client-<version> package`. Getting this error.

Comment: Should I install postgres using ubuntu or ruby? Because I need postgres with my PHP projects as well. This also removed my pgAdmin 3 software from my pc. Now I am doomed :(

Comment: Having to reinstall your DB is never fun. It's done at a system level, and this is an excellent walkthrough I use when setting up servers:

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-mysql-with-your-ruby-on-rails-application-on-ubuntu-14-04

Comment: Oops - above link is for mysql installation, below is for PSQL:

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-postgresql-with-your-ruby-on-rails-application-on-ubuntu-14-04

Comment: Mysql is working fine on my system. Ok so you want me to go through the PSQL setup again and create rails application using PSQL. Trying...

Comment: On 'sudo apt-get update' I am receiving errors. There could be alot of text, so I am adding the errors on my post.