# how to completely uninstall ruby + gems + rails out of my Ubuntu 14.04 and then start installing them as fresh

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am having a lot of issues on ruby & gem installation due to which my running projects are stopped working.

[Current issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53427182/unable-to-start-rails-server-for-a-rails-application)

Can anyone please guide me on "how to completely uninstall ruby + gems + rails out of my Ubuntu 14.04 and then start installing them as fresh".

I am also unable to remove this. Maybe once I completely throughout of my system. It may allow me to fresh install ruby n rails. Looking into this in order to make things work again.

Can anyone help?

---

If you can see my question up there, I have `rbenv, ruby and rails` installed and a lot more. I am not able to run it though. And due to which I am thinking of removing it out of my system and install them as fresh. Today, I somehow was able to fix a few issues and created a new rails application and started the server using MySQL. But, its too showing errors on other ruby lib command: `rails script/generate model Book` Rails is throwing me errors.

```
 /home/<user>/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.3/gems/railties-5.2.1/lib/rails/app_loader.rb:53: warning: Insecure world writable dir /home/<user>/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.3/bin in PATH, mode 040777
rails aborted!
Don't know how to build task 'script/generate' (see --tasks)
```

Can anyone help?

Comment: Without knowing _how_ you installed those packages, it's difficult to help you untangle them.

Comment: I installed gems using `rvm` and `rvm` and `ruby & rails` using `ubuntu apt-get`

Answer (score 2):

I highly highly recommend not touching the built-in ruby/rails/gems installation.

It's pretty standard these days to use a very lightweight manager, like [rbenv](https://github.com/rbenv/rbenv) which allows you to work with multiple versions of ruby, each with it's own installations of gems. There is also [rvm](https://rvm.io), which is a heavier manager and a bit more invasive.

Comment: Yes, you are absolutely right about it. But, I don't have much information on Ubuntu system when start throwing errors. Now, my PC is throwing errors when I try to run ruby application. And, this installation fixing & uninstalling s/w have uninstalled my pgAdmin and maybe databases as well. I need to either fix the setup or remove it completely and then reinstall it.

Comment: Or Maybe you can help me resolving the issue, I am currently having. I am clue less.

Answer (score -1):

install the newer versions with rbenv

- brew install rbenv
- rbenv init
- Close your Terminal window and open a new one so your changes take effect.
- Verify that rbenv is properly set up using this rbenv-doctor script.
- rbenv install.
- brew upgrade rbenv ruby-build

  and then install rails
  [ruby on rails setup](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-ruby-on-rails-with-rbenv-on-ubuntu-16-04)

  for database  i preferred sqlite browser

Comment: I have updated my question description about the progress I achieved today. Please check and give me solutions if you can. Thanks